# Get value after button click with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to get a value that is given by the website after a click on a button.

Here is the website: [CPF generator website](https://www.4devs.net.br/gerador-cpf)

You can see that there is a button called "Gerar CPF", this button provides a number that appears after the click.

My current script opens the browser and get the value, but I'm getting the value from the page before the click, so the value is empty. I would like to know if it is possible to get the value after the click on the button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = "https://www.4devs.net.br/gerador-cpf"

def open_browser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/willi/Documents/chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_class('btn m-1 btn-primary btn-sm').click()

def get_cpf():
    response = get(url)

    page_with_cpf = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    cpf = page_with_cpf.find("input", {"id": "__BVID__61"}).text

    print("The value is: " + cpf)


open_browser()
get_cpf()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a `while` loop in order to update the value at a time you desire. For example:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = "https://www.4devs.net.br/gerador-cpf"

def open_browser():
  driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/willi/Documents/chromedriver")
  driver.get(url)
  driver.find_element_by_class('btn m-1 btn-primary btn-sm').click()

def get_cpf():
  response = get(url)

  page_with_cpf = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

  cpf = page_with_cpf.find("input", {"id": "__BVID__61"}).text

  print("The value is: " + cpf)

while True:
   open_browser()
   get_cpf()
   time.sleep(your_time_in_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works using part of Ruggero's solution and pyperclip:

```
import time
import pyperclip
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import chromedriver_binary  # Adds chromedriver binary to path

url = "https://www.4devs.net.br/gerador-cpf"
your_time_in_s=2

def open_browser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/button[2]').click()
    time.sleep(your_time_in_s)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__BVID__60"]/div/div/div/button').click()
    print("The value is: " + pyperclip.paste())

while True:
    open_browser()
```